# Anyway to see what Application Insight SDK uploads to azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I like to inspect and check what Application Insight SDK uploads to its servers. Is there any way to do that?

Also, does Application Insight SDK compress the telemetry data in a local temp folder before uploading them? If yes, where is the temp folder?

Application Insight SDK is acting like a black box and I like to see the data being uploaded behind the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can look at the information being sent from the browser and the server.

For the client you can open up your F12 tools and view any of the calls to dc.services.visualstudio.com. Or you can use Fiddler.

On the server side you have a couple of options.

1. You can use [aistream](https://github.com/AlexBulankou/ai-stream)
2. You can use Fiddler to view the requests being made
3. You can use the built in Application Insights Visual Studio Extension